# How to render page which has enabled X-Frame option in HTML IFRAMEs

Tags: html, iframe, frame

I want one external page to be embedded in my pages via IFRAME.

Take an example:

My page contents:

```
 <html>
  <body>
  <iframe style="height: 593px; width: 100%;" src="http://xxx.com/test/"    name="urlPx2473258" id="urlPx_2473258"></iframe>
  </body>
 </html>
```

It's in the captured HTTP packets as follows:

```
   Request===>
     `GET http://xxx.com/ HTTP/1.1
      Accept: image/gif, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, image/pjpeg, application/xaml+xml,     application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument, application/x-ms-xbap, application/x-ms-application, */*
     Referer: https://plmtest2.apple.com/Agile/PLMServlet?module=LoginHandler&opcode=forwardToMainMenu
     Accept-Language: en-us
     User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.2; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
     Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
     Host: wikiserver.apple.com
     Connection: Keep-Alive

Response===>
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Date: Wed, 14 Sep 2011 22:14:30 GMT
 Server: Twisted/8.2.0 TwistedWeb/8.2.0
 Content-Length: 15626
 Accept-Ranges: bytes
 Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0, max-age=60
 Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
 Expires: Wed, 14 Sep 2011 22:15:28 GMT
 MS-Author-Via: DAV
 X-Frame-Options: SameOrigin
 X-UA-Compatible: IE=EmulateIE7
 Connection: close`
```

As can be seen, the value is set to "SameOrigin". However, the origin is app server and the frame content is from Wiki server. Therefore, the content cannot be displayed.

I can not make any changes for external page (out of my control). Is any idea I can archive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole purpose of `X-Frame-Options` is to prevent other, potentially malicious web sites from doing exactly what you're trying to do. You'll need to find some way to turn it off at the source.

Comment: I cannot turn it off at the source as the app server is out of my control. But really I have get allowed to use their page within iframe. I advised them to remove X-Frame-Options but they said no because this is being used organization wide.

Comment: You're probably out of luck, then, unless you can figure out some way to make the page containing the frame run on the same domain as the target. Also, you may want to edit the hostnames out of your packet dumps.

Comment: thanks. Is any way I can use JS, redirect or directly read the page source to put a new page that to be rendered?

Comment: You can redirect the browser to a page on the target domain, but only at the top level (e.g, `window.location = newloc`). You can't read its content from another domain, nor can you point a frame of any variety to it.

Comment: Thanks so much, Is any another way to render the external page as a portal embedded my page?

Comment: No. Again, the defining purpose of `X-Frame-Options` is to absolutely prevent other web sites from embedding a page which uses that header, to prevent certain types of "clickjacking" attacks. A workaround would be considered a security vulnerability by browser vendors, and fixed posthaste.

Comment: One more questions. If I change header of external page to 
"X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM http://10.182.222.170:8888/" then it works in firefox can be rendered correctly, but fails in IE8. get error the content cannot be render within iframe. can you help me?

Comment: `ALLOW-FROM` doesn't appear to be a recognized value for `X-Frame-Options`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header for details.